# Query using LIKE isn't working using GreenDAO

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have a table which a column is a string with three characters, each character has a value 0 or 1. I'd like to select those rows according to the case.

I'd like to perform a query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE group_type LIKE ?
```

? can be 100 or 101 or 011 or 111 or 001. A combination with 0 and 1 in three characters.

I'm trying to query using LIKE

```
WhereCondition where = null;
switch (condition) {
    case case1:
        where = ItemDao.Properties.GroupType.like("1%");
        break;
    case case2:
        where = ItemDao.Properties.GroupType.like("%1%");
        break;
    case case3:
        where = ItemDao.Properties.GroupType.like("%1");
        break;
}
List<Item> items = itemDao.queryBuilder().where(where).list();
```

case1 is returning everything that starts with 1 as expected.
case3 is returning everything that ends with 1 as expected.
case2 is returning everything! It doesn't metter the value in the beggining, middle or end. It's returning everything.

case1 and case3 are working fine. However, case2 isn't working. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: You must elaborate more on how exactly the case2 doesn't work? What is the output..?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please take a look

Comment: Well that's to be expected, each of these numbers contains a 1. It does not mean it **must** have something before and after it, %1% means that it can, but doesn't have to have something before and after.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Well I have thought of a hacky way to do it, to post-filter the data ( I don't think the query can be much improved ). Get all the data and the parse the string to see if it contains the '1', and if it does, does it have something before and after it. I'm quite sorry, but that's all I got.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it. However I think to query direcly is better. I also tought about create 3 columns which means each case...

Comment: It is still not completely clear what you expect for case2, but if you want your like clause to match every 3 char string with '1' in second position, you can use the underscore wildcard (`_`) for first and third char, i.e., `like("_1_")`.

Comment: @gcressier I didn't know about wildcard, it will solve the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. "%1%" is supposed to return everything where "1" occurs. It can be "100", "010" or "101", but not "000".

Answer (score 0):

From the [sqlite like clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm) reference page:

> *The percent sign represents **zero, one, or multiple** numbers or characters.* The underscore represents a single number or character. These symbols can be used in combinations.

**By saying `%1%` you are searching for elements that have at least one number 1, regardless where it may be.** This is mostly because % meaning zero, one or multiple occurrences. This is further explained in that link by the following example:

> WHERE SALARY LIKE '%200%'
>
> Finds any values that have 200 **in any position**

So we can see that indeed you are getting the expected behavior.